# Illustrator: Clip using transparency

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, mask

I want to clip the image in the background using the image on top based on the transparency

[image]

Original link: http://prntscr.com/8brfnb

I want the areas that are under the opaque parts of the top image to be deleted/subtracted

Is this possible with Illustrator? How can it be done?

Comment: Uhm isn't that the default behaviour? The opaque areas of the upper image will conceal the image below, whereas the transparent areas won't ...

Comment: I need to print the design without the mask, is it possible to do some kind of graphical subtraction?

Comment: You cannot delete pieces of raster images in Illustrator, but you can use a clipping mask that is the same size as the watch opening to hide the edges of the photo. Do you know how to do that?